# When do you drop the absolute value from ln|x| + C when integrating $\frac{1}{u}du$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given:  p(t) represents the number of cats, when t>=0.
Given:  p(t) is increasing at a rate directly proportional to $800-p(t)$

So, I represent this as:  $\frac{dp}{dt}= k(800-P)$

I want p(t), so I separate and integrate:  $\int{\frac{dp}{800-p}} = \int{kdt}$

When I integrate, I am told this yields $-ln(800-p)=kt+c$

Shouldn't it be:  $-ln|800-p|=kt+c$?

Why did they drop the absolute value?
Is the phrasing of the givens implying that $800-p$ is always positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given only the information stated, the only reason we can assume that 800-p isn't negative is that we are taking its logarithm. This makes sense in terms of the model; 800 is functioning as a population ceiling, as the rate of increase slows down as $p$ approaches 800.

Comment: Yes, when p=800, dp/dt = 0, and there can be more more cats.  So, P maxes out at 800, and therefore, 800-P can never be negative.

Comment: @JackOfAll if you solve the equation, you'll see that p actually never becomes equal to 800 with the likely starting conditions.

Comment: Solve which?  I can't solve for P(t) until I resolve the issue with using ln|x| vs. ln(x), so I wouldn't know the result yet.  Trying to determine how I'd know to use ln(x) at this very step.

Comment: Solve it assuming the quantity is positive.

Comment: Right, but my question is: why can you assume the quantity is positive?

Comment: When $800-p$ is negative, $p$ is decreasing unless $k$ is negative. We are told that $p$ is increasing. They intend to bound the population by 800, even though they don't say it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is likely to be due to the fact that $800-p$ cannot be negative. I don't quite know what 800 represents but it seems likely that $800-p$ cant be a negative number otherwise it doesn't work out. Hope this makes sense. Would have added this as a comment but I cant presently.

Comment: Right, but why can we assume that $800-p$ can't be negative?

Comment: Which is why you need to provide us with more information about the biological context. For example, what does the 800 represent? Is it some sort of steady state?

Comment: I have written the given verbatim as it was provided.

Comment: For a mathematician, the problem is not well formulated. But the wording “*increasing* at a rate proportional to $800-p$” gives me the slightest hope that $800-p$ is positive.